# Same Jsoup code behaving differently on Android and desktop

Tags: java, android, html-parsing, jsoup

I've got 5-line, simple Jsoup code parsing some strings, it smoothly runs and returns an array list with values that i want, however on android emulator and phone, it just returns nothing without even giving an error.

Thats the whole code :

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(myURL).get();
Elements els = doc.select("div font a");
for (int i = 3; i < els.size(); i++) {
    latestNews.add(els.get(i).text());
}
```

On desktop, it adds elements into array list, however on device, nothing occurs. Could anyone help about it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you are receiving the same HTML from the site? you should debug and check your `doc` variable to make sure it contains the same HTML as you'd expect on the site. Possible case of grabbing the mobile site when you are parsing the full site? (not sure if Jsoup prevents getting the mobile site or not). You likely need to set the user agent so that you receive the full desktop variant of the website.

ex.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(myURL).userAgent("Mozilla").get();
```

Comment: These are the exact same lines of my android project on eclipse and simple try project on netbeans. i can't see how to debug, it does not give any error while trying to parse..

Comment: In eclipse put a breakpoint on the line "Document doc = Jsoup.connect(myURL).get();" Right click your Android project, select Debug as and then pick "Android application" it will pause on that line when you run it. Click "Step over" to get to the next line. Examine the "doc" variable (hover over it with your mouse). you can then see the HTML it received

Comment: i can't now debug it since phone and computer got screwed up but it's just weird, i put simply hello, world string after the line Document doc = ... , it's not printed out.

Comment: Did you try setting the user agent? I edited my answer to include an example of how to do that

Comment: It now gives the exception UnknownException + the website url. does it mean it can't handle it on device ? the website im trying to parse does not have a mobile specific site. i tried user agent, but it did not change.

Comment: Do you you have <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> set in your androidmanifest.xml?

Comment: I solved it, it's stupid, it caused because the internet permission tag on androidmanifest.xml appeared after the application tag, not before it.. thank you btw.

Comment: it is the application that uses the internet and it does not want itself the permission tag within its scope. idiot.